# Safari table cell size

Tags: css, safari, css-tables

The CSS code of the table is:

```
table.ctable td {
   width:60px;
   height:60px;
}
```

But in Safari browser the table cell height is bigger than the width (I did not set the whole table dimensions).

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post full HTML of this?

Answer (score -2):

There is padding on all sides of the element. So you must remove them.

```
table.ctable td {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  padding:0 0 0 0;
}
```